# Python read and separate string and data

Tags: python

I have an input file with this format

```
{A}
4.240000     1.593631     1.593631
4.240000    -1.593631     1.593631
4.240000    -1.593631    -1.593631
4.240000     1.593631    -1.593631
{B}
-4.240000    -1.593631    -1.593631
-4.240000     1.593631    -1.593631
{C}
...
```

I want to read {A}, save the array below, work with the array and then move to {B} do the same,...

I have something like this

```
import sys

#Read file
inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile) as vfile:
line = vfile.readline()

while line:

    if line.find("{") == 0:
        A = line.split('\n')
    else:
        line.split()
        array = []
        line = [int(i) in line]
        array.append(line)
    print(A, array)
```

Comment: and your question iiis....?

Comment: do you need a separate arrays or just print the between lines?

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

data = {}
key = None
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.endswith('}'):
        key = line[1:-1]
        data[key] = []
    elif line and key is not None:
        # if the number of spaces can be different
        values = re.split('\s+', line)
        data[key].extend(map(float, values))
```

And you will get data like:

```
{'A': [4.24, 1.593631, 1.593631, ...], 'B': [-4.24, -1.593631, -1.59, ...] ...}
```